# JNI: does GetStringUTFChars() throw an OOM on failure or not?

Tags: java-native-interface, out-of-memory

I am currently working on a project of mine which will use JNI heavily, and JNI is quite new to me... I am reading a lot about it, and I have one problem: in one native function, I want to return an integer which is the state of the operation, and in the event where I cannot allocate strings using GetStringUTFChars(), I want to return a specific error code.

But I have two documentations which seem to disagree:

- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html, section 3.2.1, says this function throws an OOM on failure;
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html doesn't say it does (I say it because other functions on this page which do throw OOM are specified as such).

I tend to believe the second documentation since it is newer. Am I misguided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well, after playing with ulimits and such to get to trigger a native failure, I got a JVM crash due to not being able to malloc() for GetStringUTFChars() :/

I guess I'll just assume it returns NULL on failure and be done with it, although I very much doubt this will ever happen -- the JVM will certainly crash before, heh.

Answer (score 2):

I think the two sets of documentation agree (at least the versions I'm looking at now).

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html:

> Do not forget to check the return value of GetStringUTFChars. Because the Java virtual machine implementation needs to allocate memory to hold the UTF-8 string, there is a chance that memory allocation will fail. When that happens, GetStringUTFChars returns NULL and throws an OutOfMemoryError exception. As we will learn in Chapter 6, throwing an exception through the JNI is different from throwing an exception in the Java programming language. A pending exception thrown through the JNI does not automatically change control flow in native C code. Instead, we need to issue an explicit return statement in order to skip the remaining statements in the C function. After Java_Prompt_getLine returns, the exception will be thrown in Prompt.main, caller of the Prompt.getLine native method.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html:

> RETURNS:
>
> Returns a pointer to a modified UTF-8 string, or NULL if the operation fails.

So both state that `NULL` is returned on failure, but the first goes further and states that once the JNI C++ function returns, an exception will be thrown within the Java layer.